# вывести в консоль количество аккаунтов привязанных к телефону. Runtime permission

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, account

Прошу подсказки более опытных коллег, мне нужно вывести кол-во привязанных аккаунтов к телефону в консоль , я для этого использую AccountManager :

```
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

    Log.i("Size", "Size: " + accounts.length);
    

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AccountActivity.this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
```

Разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

В итоге получаю 0, поискав информацию в интернете стало понятно , что  не хватает разрешений,  но разрешения  прописываются в рантайме.
Попробовал не получилось.
Как корректно прописать запрос в рантайме ? Может еще каких то  разрешений не хватает ?
3 дня борюсь с 3 строчками кода...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918731/get-list-of-accounts-in-android вот так попробуйте

Comment: Переписал код , запрос на разрешение доступа к контактам разрешил , но все равно получил в консоли ноль ..

Comment: а вы где тестируете?

Comment: Не на эмуляторе, на своем телефоне.

Comment: попробуйте поискать в документации, вот например - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#getAccountsByType(java.lang.String)

Comment: Спасибо, читал документацию, там описывается необходимость максимального оповещения пользователя при попытке вытянуть аккаунты... Но примеров я не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Причина оказалась в том , что  permission GET_ACCOUNTS устарел!
Вероятно GET_ACCOUNTS на старых версиях Андроид  сработает но на новых версия  нужно использовать READ_CONTACTS ,  обязательно в рантайм. Код прикрепляю ниже.

```
  if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AccountActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        )
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
        Log.i("acount", String.valueOf(accounts.length));
        for(Account account: accounts)
        {
            Log.i("acount", String.valueOf(account));
            //делаем что- то 
        }
```